# How to create XPT file from excel using R

Tags: r, sas

I need to convert an Excel file(xls/xlsx) to xpt file using R. I have downloaded and installed RStudio and R but i am unable to convert my excel file to xpt.

I have tried following thing:

1. downloaded "readxl" and "sasxport" packages
2. used "write.xport" for creating the xpt file
3. used "lookup.xport" for displaying the xpt file

I used SAS XPORT file viewer for viewing the xpt file but it shows some distorted output. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What code did you run?

Comment: Please include your R code. We're also assuming you have no access to SAS. Are you affiliated with academia? If so, you can get a free version of SAS to work with.

Comment: Use [haven](https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/07/13/haven-1-1-0/). It is faster and better in handling these files. [more details](https://haven.tidyverse.org/reference/read_xpt.html)

Answer (score 1):

SAS studio will convert this from xlsx to xpt extension.

Need to install SAS studio and share path.
code:

```
libname mydata '/folders/myfolders/';
libname in xlsx "/folders/myfolders/Nike AOC form-1180808330 (2).xlsx";
libname out xport "/folders/myfolders/Nike AOC form-1180808330 (2).xpt";
proc copy inlib=in outlib=out;
run;
```

Thats all and it will convert to XPT.

Comment: This assumes SAS that the OP doesn't seem to have. SAS Studio does have license restrictions, which does not include commercial usage. It is not open source.